Nginx Proxy Pass to Rails Application Fails - Connection Refused on [::1]:3000
I'm setting up a Ruby on Rails application behind Nginx with SSL. I've configured Nginx to proxy requests to my Rails app running on port 3000. However, I'm receiving a connection refused error when trying to access the site through Nginx.
Steps Taken:
Confirmed that Puma is running and listening on port 3000.
Checked firewall rules and port status.
Verified Nginx configuration and permissions.
Ensured Rails application is running.
Issue:
Despite the Rails application running and accepting connections locally on port 3000, Nginx reports a connection refused error when trying to proxy requests to it.
Question:
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Are there any additional checks or configurations I should consider?
Nginx Configuration:
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name raitrr.com www.raitrr.com;

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # Let’s Encrypt challenge location
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name raitrr.com www.raitrr.com;

    # Paths to your Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/raitrr.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/raitrr.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Recommended SSL settings
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Location for your Rails application
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Nginx Error Log:
2024/08/31 00:04:37 [error] 883#883: *26 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.59.109.142, server: raitrr.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/", host: "raitrr.com"
Rails Log:
Started GET "/.git/config" for 64.62.197.165 at 2024-08-31 01:35:25 +0000
Cannot render console from 64.62.197.165! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/.git/config"):


"Confirmed that Puma is running and listening on port 3000." - correct port is not sufficient. ::1 is the IPv6 address for localhost. Make sure that a) the rails app is really listening to IPv6 too and not just IPv4 (check netstat). Also this expects nginx and the app to run on the same machine and in case of containers the same container - is this really the case? And please provide an actual prove that these requirements are met in your question (edit it) instead of only claiming that you've checked it.

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/.git/config") states that you don't have a route for that path.

I finally resolved the issue by upgrading rails to 7.2, first I installed everything locally and got everything working. Then I cloned GitHub repo on server. Works now on the internet. Configured nginx to proxie pass to rails in http and puma picks it up from there
